# Return predefined schema object as response in openAPI

Tags: openapi, jsonschema

What I want to do is define a schema in my openAPI spec and have the schema be a return so that the request can send an array of schemas back that are predefined.  So, for example, here are the schemas:

```
    "components" : {
        "schemas": {
            "weight_kg": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The weight of the animal in kilograms (kg)",
                "minimum": 0,
                "maximum": 11000,
                "example": 3.9
            },
            "length_m": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The length of the animal in meters (m)",
                "minimum": 0,
                "maximum": 20,
                "example": 0.78
            },
            "height_m": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The height of the animal in meters (m)",
                "minimum": 0,
                "maximum": 6,
                "example": 0.25
            }
        }
    }
```

Now trying to use those schemas:

```
"paths": {
    "/required_info": {
        "get": {
            "description": "Request required animal info to operate",
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "The required animal info to operate",
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "description": "Array of required animal info field schemas to operate",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "schema",
                                    "description": "A schema to collect information against",
                                    "enum": [
                                        "#/components/schemas/weight_kg",
                                        "#/components/schemas/length_m",
                                        "#/components/schemas/height_m"
                                },
                                "example": [
                                    "length_m": {
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "description": "The length of the animal in meters (m)",
                                        "minimum": 0,
                                        "maximum": 20,
                                        "example": 0.78
                                    },
                                    "height_m": {
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "description": "The height of the animal in meters (m)",
                                        "minimum": 0,
                                        "maximum": 6,
                                        "example": 0.25
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So of course my openAPI above is wrong, but I'm just trying to show what I wish was possible but I'm pretty sure isn't.  The example is what I want to come back as a response.  Any ideas on how to address this kind of functionality are appreciated.  I've searched a pretty good amount but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The example is what I want to come back as a response

The simplest thing you can do is replacing `"example"` with `"const"` in your schema. By doing that, you define a schema which matches exactly 1 value. You can (but don't have to) also delete the `"type"` and `"items"` from your schema, since the `"const"` explains everything on its own.